# Is there an idiomatic way to express being overwhelmed by vocabulary?

Tags: idioms

The other day, I wanted to describe my shock regarding the overwhelming HSK6 vocabulary list (~2500 additional words) to my teacher, so I came up with a self-made idiom 词山词海: taking 人山人海 and replacing 人 with 词.  I thought it was apt and quite proud of my creation, by my teacher disagreed.

I can't think of an idiomatic way to express this sense of being overwhelmed by vocabulary when learning a language in Chinese.  Sure, I could say 词汇太多了, but it doesn't have the sense of being overwhelmed.

**Question**: Is there an idiomatic way to express being overwhelmed by vocabulary?

Comment: How about 万词淹没, (Wàn cí yān mò) ( a flood of words or drowned in words)?

Comment: 词山词海 is fine though it's a bit odd.  People could see you were trying to do a bit wordplay on the idiom 人山人海. It's easy to understand what you mean by that. It could have a potential to become a meme in my opinion. Language needs creativity.

Comment: @WayneCheah Nah, it sounds even a bit weirder than 词山词海.

Comment: I feel a bit vindicated after seeing a shop with the name [鱼山鱼海](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PDHv.jpg).

Answer (score 3):

无从说起：
指事情太繁杂，要说的话很多，但不知道该从哪里说起。

Things are too complicated and there are many things to say, but don’t know where to start.

一言难尽：形容事情曲折复杂，不是一句话能说清楚的。

Describe things tortuous and complex, a sentence cannot make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

There are idioms that express shock and dismay, but none are specifically referring to facing too heavy a task, let alone describing a specific task that is to learn a large number of words.

My suggestion is:

看到 HSK6 词汇表上这堆积如山的词汇，登時目瞪口呆

you can replace 堆积如山  with any idiom or idiomatic phrase that describes a huge quantity, e.g. 为数惊​​人，数以百计，密密麻麻，重重叠叠，多不胜数，既多且难... etc.

you can replace 目瞪口呆 with any idiom or idiomatic phrase that expresses your dismay, e.g. 叫苦连天，欲哭无泪，气为之馁，大吃一惊，望而生畏... etc.

you can replace 登时 with 顿时，不禁... etc.

Comment: I personally would say 吓尿了, but I don't think your teacher would like it.

Comment: I think the correct spelling is 堆积如山 （or 堆積如山 in traditional). 禾字旁

Comment: Perhaps it's also 目瞪口呆 (not 目定口呆).

Comment: Cantonese say 目定口呆. I thought Mandarin speaker would understand

Answer (score 1):

I like 不知所措 for 'overwhelmed'. (Wonder what 'underwhelmed' might be? 知所措？？）

生词量大得让我不知所措。
I am overwhelmed by the sheer number of new words.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is one expressing this very situation,  but you can just phrasing one like ancient scholars do:

学习HSK6，正如孤舟济辞海——没于洪涛！

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

心灰意懒

> 那么多的词，看着就让我觉得**心灰意懒**！

精疲力尽

> 那么多词，还没学就已经**精疲力尽**了。